# Series with coefficients 0 and 1

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of series with coefficients 0 and 1 which is not rational function.

Can anyone help to this problem?

Comment: A power series like $\sum z^{n!}$?

Comment: @LutzL,Yes power series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it would be good example.
Moreover you must prove it strictly.

$$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}{x^{2^k}}\notin \mathbb{Q}[x]$$

Answer (score 2):

The coefficients of the series for a rational function obey a linear recursion equation that is defined by the coefficients of the denominator.

Thus any coefficient series that has zero gaps of increasing length can not belong to a rational function.